Не удается подключиться по RCON при помощи библиотеке Mctools
from mctools import RCONClient 
import config

def add_whitelist(host, port, nick):
        rcon = RCONClient(host=host, port=port)
        rcon.login(config.RconPass)
        rcon.command(f"whitelist add {nick}")

add_whitelist(config.ip, config.port, 'fyhe')
    

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
Как исправить?

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Можете погуглить ошибку 10061б это звучит как что-то стандартное системное

Перевожу с технического на русский — подключаться не к чему, порт никто не слушает
